# Vaadin - How to use Valo font Open Sans without Valo theme?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-valo-theme

In my Vaadin app I'm using my theme based on Vaadin Base theme.
How can I use Valo font Open Sans if I don't use Valo theme?

My styles.scss

```
@import "../valo/fonts/open-sans/_open-sans.scss";

.myTheme {
..
@include font-open-sans;
..
font-family: 'Open Sans';
..
}
```

But it don't work.
Hope it's clear enough, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you looked with the inspector what css rules are finally present?

Answer (score 3):

I found solution.

In result styles.ccs @font-face rule has to be outside own theme.
So, my styles.scss:

```
@import "../valo/fonts/open-sans/_open-sans.scss";
@include font-open-sans(true, true, true, true, true, true);

.myTheme {
   ...
}
```